# How to merge two wordpress queries and randomize?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, foreach

I am getting two different custom post types from my WordPress database.

$data1   = ...

$actions = ...

Now, I am listing and looping through $data1.
Is it possible that, when I loop though $data, I show some data from $actions? I want for example, three records of data1, and one from actions, and then 2 records from data1, and again one from action,... ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the WP Query in such a way that it isn't setting the MAIN query. By running two separate queries you can iterate through each without impacting the other.

Once you have them broken into two separate queries, all you need to do is define your algorithm for iterating through them.